# Function design accepting callback best practices

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm designing a module for an API where on some of the methods it only makes sense to specify a callback if you care about the result. An example would be a request to store some data, where the response would be information about the data stored (internal id's, time-stamps, etc.). I understand that the code the function should be:

```
MyFunc.prototype.putRecord = function(data, next){
    var self = this;
    //Any validation and transformation
    api.storeRecord(data, function(err, data){
        next(err, data);
    });
};
```

My question is how to design it so that when `next === "undefined"`, my module would not throw an error. If the `api.storeRecord` call does return an error, I would still want the error to be thrown if the `next` parameter is not supplied. 
I was thinking of creating a helper function that would handle checking if `next` is defined, calling it if so, or throwing the error if one occurred:

```
function callNext(err, res, next){
    if (next) next(err, data);
    else if (err) throw err;
};
```

I could then call this function instead of `next`:

```
MyFunc.prototype.putRecord = function(data, next){
    var self = this;
    //Any validation and transformation
    api.storeRecord(data, function(err, data){
        callNext(err, data, next);
    });
};
```

Is this the best way to go about what I am wanting to do, or is there another way that is considered standard?

Comment: The completely different solution would be to return a promise instead of accepting a callback

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for pointing out Promises. I did not know about those and they are really useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it a little cleaner. Since your handler does nothing but forward the call, you can actually eliminate it completely. You do need to take care of invalid / missing `next` in order to throw the proper `err` like you did. Here's how I'd do it using the callback scheme:

```
function throwHandler(err) {
  if(err) {
    throw err;
  }
}

function nextOrHandler(next) {
    if('function' === typeof next) {
      return next;
    }
    return throwHandler;
};

MyFunc.prototype.putRecord = function(data, next) {
    api.storeRecord(data, nextOrHandler(next));
}
```